# STM32 HAL_FLASH_Program not working as expected

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to program FLASH using `HAL_FLASH_Program()` function. Precisely speaking, I've written a function which is expected to write two measurements 
to flash at a set time interval (e.g. 3 seconds). However, when called, the function manages to write only the first one while ignoring the second one. Can't `HAL_FLASH_Program` be used twice? What am I doing wrong? I just want to mention that I'm utterly new to STM32 programming, so any helpful suggestions would be much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
void writeFlash(void){  
  mem = returnPointerToFirstEmptyAddressInSector();
  Address = (uint32_t)mem;
  var1.f = Temperature;
  var2.f = SD;
  HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
  __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_OPERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGPERR);
  HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, Address, var1.i );
  Address++; 
  HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, Address, var2.i); 
  HAL_FLASH_Lock();

}
```

Comment: You should check `HAL_FLASH_Program` return. If it fails check the error code. Maybe you need to check de `BSY` bit in the `FLASH_SR` register before do the second write or the lock.

Comment: Check also voltage range as some types of FLASH programming are disallowed for different voltage ranges.

Comment: Did you try with different incrementation of `Address` variable? E.g. `Address += 2` or `Address += 4`

Answer (score 4):

**The address is not properly aligned**

The declaration of `Address` is not shown, but from the line

```
Address = (uint32_t)mem;
```

I'd guess it's an `unsigned long`. Later, you are incrementing `Address` after the first write with

```
Address++;
```

and use this value to program the second value. But since `Address` is presumably an integer, not a pointer type, **it would be incremented by one instead of the word size (4)**, and pointing to an address that is partially overlapping the previously written value, and not aligned for word-sized writes. The second write operation would inevitably fail. As @JMA suggests in the comments, check the return value of `HAL_FLASH_Program()`, and the error code

```
uint32_t ret = HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, Address, var2.i);
switch(ret) {
    case HAL_OK:
        break;
    case HAL_TIMEOUT:
        printf("HAL_FLASH_Program() timeout!\n");
        break;
    case HAL_ERROR:
        printf("HAL_FLASH_Program() error 0x%08x, see *hal_flash.h for bit definitions\n", HAL_FLASH_GetError());
        break;
    default:
        printf("HAL_FLASH_Program() returned unknown status %lu\n", ret);
}
```

**Write a double word at once**

The HAL library supports writing 64 bit values at once, so you can write two 32 bit integers in one operation.

```
HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, Address, ((uint64_t)var2.i << 32) | var1.i);
```

Just ensure that `Address` is aligned to a doubleword boundary, i.e. divisible by 8.

Comment: And there is no byte flash write as well.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 some of them can do 8 bit flash writes, e.g. F4

Comment: he did not reveal the model. So generally the 16b write is safe for all models.

Comment: STM32H7 writes 32 bytes at a time.